# Save an text from Google Speech-to-text to cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

Is it possible to directly save the text from speech to text to cloud storage using python client library?

At the moment I was able to perform this save operation only by waiting for the end of the speech-to-text operation, saving the text stack as a file and only then uploading it to the storage bucket

Comment: I think you can eliminate the step of saving output from speech-to-text in a file and then uploading. Instead you can upload the output obtained from the speech-to-text to GCS directly. One such example: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-write-and-get-a-json-file-in-google-cloud-storage-when-deploying-flask-api-in-google-app-9121fa936d85

Comment: @AishwaryShukla 
Thanks, but I'm looking for an asynchronous way - that is, not to wait until the operation is done, but at the end of the operation, the saving to the bucket will be done.
I know that in the google video intelligence api there is an option to do this with the command
operation = video_client.annotate_video(
         request={"features": features,
                  "input_uri": gcs_uri,
                  "output_uri": output_uri,
                  "video_context": video_context}
     )

Comment: Hi, I have seen that you also asked the same question in GCC. Filing a feature request can be helpful for GCP to add it subsequently.